# Error:MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, i am getting this error massage,once i opned xampp server

Tags: xampp

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 00:39:45

This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 00:39:45

improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 00:39:45

Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 00:39:45

the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 00:39:45

If you need more help, copy and post this 00:39:45

entire log window on the forums

i tried , delete info files in xampp , data folder and restared the xampp server.
it's worked, somehow after another 3 , 2 days , same issue appears.

Comment: So what information is found when `Press the Logs button to view error logs`? ... or also in the `Windows Event Viewer` ?

Comment: 2024-03-10  0:34:42 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=243] log sequence number 170522 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 65951.
2024-03-10  0:34:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-03-10  0:34:42 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corr

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
above logs were generating while i was trying to work with xampp.....